# Solr Phonetic Algorithm for Person Name Search

Tags: solr

I’m new to Solr and trying to use Solr for Person search in our project. Person record with fields like name, date of birth, gender and address. We tried using various fuzzy filters and phonetic filters to retrieve person record and getting decent results.

For Phonetic algorithm, we are using Beider Morse Phonetic Algorithm which is comparatively better than other algorithms we have tried so far. I would like to know if anyone has used Solr very specifically for Person search and could you please share you experience with Phonetic algorithm that you have used for name match and any comparative study on those.

Many Thanks

Comment: I assume that by "Person" you mean you are looking for peoples **names** on the file base? Would be nice to edit your question if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks Anika, added clarification on the person details.

Answer (score 1):

Name matching is quite a common use case for Solr, so I am sure there are lots of people with experience in it.

But I don't think just picking the best phonetic filter will be enough. No matter what you are going to need to customize it for your specific case. For instance:

- besides names/surnames etc, I typically have always encountered other fields (nationality, age, gender...). You do too. You typically leverage those as fq or for just boosting.
- are false positive or false negatives equally bad or one is less severe than the other?
- your corpus contains a single language or the names can be from anywhere in the world?

and on and on. Basis has a commercial product for this I think you can see [their presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UtMrQrkDlc) at Lucene/Solr revolution 2015 on this subject

Comment: Thanks Persimmonium. We are considering other aspects like nicknames, partial names, out of order names, etc and also other fields like age, address in determining the score of the result set. I wasn't sure on the phonetic algorithm, and using Beider Morse as of now. Names we have is not just English, and read Beider Morse could handle many other language as well. If there is any suggestion on other algorithm would try that.

Comment: my point is that other stuff in your final score (in my last setup for this I ended up doing a quite complex edismax with reranking) will have more effect than using Beider Morse or some other phonetic algo

Comment: I see that now, thank you very much for your suggestion and your time!